# what's the purpose of ReturnJob in IJobFactory Interface for Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, simple-injector

I'm using simpleInjector as IOC container bue I dont have a clear view of what's the responsabillity of **ReturnJob**, I'd like to know how can I proceed?

this is the code I have done so far:

```
public class SimpleInjectorJobFactory:IJobFactory
    {
        private readonly Container _container;
        public SimpleInjectorJobFactory()
        {
            _container= new Container();
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method allow returning the instance back to IoC container & Job factory for proper cleanup.

Check [this commit](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/65) on github.

Comment: adding link to the implementation of StructureMap for Quartz.Net https://gist.github.com/Saanch/2c1e63b225ff5d13d145

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up the job;

```
   public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
   {
       (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
   }
```